# Hide form's DoubleBuffered property without make it nonfunctional

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Using a `Class` I am trying to hide the `DoubleBuffered` property from form's property window but without make it nonfunctional. So I did something like this in code example below... Ηowever, `DoubleBuffered` property still appears. So, can we really hide `DoubleBuffered` property and if yes, how can we do that?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    <Browsable(False)>
    Public Overloads Property DoubleBuffered As Boolean
        Get
            Return MyBase.DoubleBuffered
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            MyBase.DoubleBuffered = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney: No we haven't talk about this before, at least not together. Well I tried to override it `Public Overrides Property DoubleBuffered As Boolean` but I get this `Public Overrides Property DoubleBuffered As Boolean' cannot override 'Protected Overridable Overloads Property DoubleBuffered As Boolean' because they have different access levels.`. Then I tried to shadow like this `Public Shadows Property DoubleBuffered As Boolean` but property is still there.

Comment: I deleted my comment because, in testing, it seemed not be true. I tested and read a bit more though and realised that what I had said was generally true but, in fact, `DoubleBuffered` appears to be a special case. It is actually a `Protected` member of the `Control` class so it shouldn't appear in the Properties window anyway. It doesn't for controls. I can only conclude that the WinForms designer has been written to explicitly add that property to the Properties window for forms, so I don't think that there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: That this is a protected property gives some insight, you can't normally edit protected properties in the Properties window.  The designer fixes this problem by "virtualizing" the property, the DocumentDesigner.PreFilterProperties() method uses TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty() under the hood.  Getting rid of it again without completely reimplementing the FormDocumentDesigner class, erm, throw in the towel.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I am working on a custom form, not a control!!! Thank you for the answer, was helpful!!!

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you mean that maybe I can achieve that by using a custom designer?

Comment: Sure, you have to replace the designer for the Form class (normally the internal FormDocumentDesigner class) so this TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty() call is not made.  There is no RemoveProperty() method.  Anything is possible, but hard to imagine that you won't conclude you need more towels.

Comment: "I am working on a custom form, not a control!!!". The DoubleBuffered property is a member of the Control class. It is thus inherited by all classes derived from Control, which includes Form and thus anything derived from Form. Because DoubleBuffered is declared Protected, it doesn't appear in the Properties window by default. You can check for any control and you'll see that it's not there. In the case of a Form though, it IS displayed, which means something specific to Form is done to make it appear.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hmmm ... Is there any example or something that will guide me? I had done something similar for a `UserControl` but it doesn't seems to work in this case...

Comment: @HansPassant: Oh, you mean that I have to give it up... If I am not wrong this time lol!!!

Comment: You can't access a protected property of a control unless you inherit from that control. When you create a form, it inherits from Forms, that's why you have access to all protected property of a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom component designer for your Form, but that is a daunting task to just recreate the functionality of the inaccessible `System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner`.  The simpler way is use the Form's Site property as I have shown you before to access the designer services.

In this case, you need to override the [ITypeDescriptorFilterService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.itypedescriptorfilterservice(v=vs.110).aspx) service of the designer host.  This service is used by the designer for all type discovery/filtering operations and is not limited to a specific component.

The first step is to create a class that implements `ITypeDescriptorFilterService`.  The following is one such implementation.  It is a generic implementation that allows it to filter components of the specified type and takes list of property names that you want to exclude from the PropertyGrid display.  The final item it requires is a reference to the existing service used by the designer host.

```
Friend Class FilterService(Of T) : Implements ITypeDescriptorFilterService
    Private namesOfPropertiesToRemove As String()

    Public Sub New(baseService As ITypeDescriptorFilterService, ParamArray NamesOfPropertiesToRemove As String())
        Me.BaseService = baseService
        Me.namesOfPropertiesToRemove = NamesOfPropertiesToRemove
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property BaseService As ITypeDescriptorFilterService
    Public Function FilterAttributes(component As IComponent, attributes As IDictionary) As Boolean Implements ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterAttributes
        Return BaseService.FilterAttributes(component, attributes)
    End Function

    Public Function FilterEvents(component As IComponent, events As IDictionary) As Boolean Implements ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterEvents
        Return BaseService.FilterEvents(component, events)
    End Function

    Public Function FilterProperties(component As IComponent, properties As IDictionary) As Boolean Implements ITypeDescriptorFilterService.FilterProperties
        ' ref: ITypeDescriptorFilterService Interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.itypedescriptorfilterservice(v=vs.110).aspx
        ' 
        ' The return value of FilterProperties determines if this set of properties is fixed.
        ' If this method returns true, the TypeDescriptor for this component can cache the 
        ' results. This cache is maintained until either the component is garbage collected or the Refresh method of the type descriptor is called.

        ' allow other filters 1st chance to modify the properties collection
        Dim ret As Boolean = BaseService.FilterProperties(component, properties)

        ' only remove properties if component is of type T
        If TypeOf component Is T AndAlso Not (properties.IsFixedSize Or properties.IsReadOnly) Then
            For Each propName As String In namesOfPropertiesToRemove
                ' If the IDictionary object does not contain an element with the specified key, 
                ' the IDictionary remains unchanged. No exception is thrown.
                properties.Remove(propName)
            Next
        End If
        Return ret
    End Function
End Class
```

**Example Usage in Form:**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

Public Class TestForm : Inherits Form
    Private host As IDesignerHost
    Private altTypeDescriptorProvider As FilterService(Of TestForm)

    ' spelling and character casing of removedPropertyNames is critical
    ' it is a case-sensative lookup
    Private Shared removedPropertyNames As String() = {"DoubleBuffered"}

    Public Overrides Property Site As ISite
        Get
            Return MyBase.Site
        End Get
        Set(value As ISite)
            If host IsNot Nothing Then
                UnwireDesignerCode()
            End If

            MyBase.Site = value
            If value IsNot Nothing Then
                host = CType(Site.GetService(GetType(IDesignerHost)), IDesignerHost)
                If host IsNot Nothing Then
                    If host.Loading Then
                        AddHandler host.LoadComplete, AddressOf HostLoaded
                    Else
                        WireUpDesignerCode()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub HostLoaded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RemoveHandler host.LoadComplete, AddressOf HostLoaded
        WireUpDesignerCode()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireUpDesignerCode()
        AddFilter()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnwireDesignerCode()
        If host IsNot Nothing Then
            RemoveFilter()
        End If
        host = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddFilter()
        Dim baseFilter As ITypeDescriptorFilterService = CType(host.GetService(GetType(ITypeDescriptorFilterService)), ITypeDescriptorFilterService)
        If baseFilter IsNot Nothing Then
            ' remove existing filter service
            host.RemoveService(GetType(ITypeDescriptorFilterService))
            ' create our replacement service and add it to the host's services
            altTypeDescriptorProvider = New FilterService(Of TestForm)(baseFilter, removedPropertyNames)
            host.AddService(GetType(ITypeDescriptorFilterService), altTypeDescriptorProvider)
            TypeDescriptor.Refresh(Me.GetType) ' force a type description rescan 
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveFilter()
        If altTypeDescriptorProvider IsNot Nothing Then
            host.RemoveService(GetType(ITypeDescriptorFilterService))
            host.AddService(GetType(ITypeDescriptorFilterService), altTypeDescriptorProvider.BaseService)
            altTypeDescriptorProvider = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now when you create a form that inherits from `TestForm`, the `DoubleBuffered` property will be excluded from the PropertyGrid display.

[image]

Comment: I bow down my friend, it worked 100%!!! Thank you very much for your time!!! :) Now I have to study your example line by line, also to read your in-line comments and try to understand what this example really do. One more question to be sure... The `DoubleBuffered` property excluded from the **PropertyGrid** display but is still functional right?

Comment: @Simonetos The Greek, please understand that type information edited by these methods in no way alters the underlying code definition.  This is what is referred to as type metadata.  At design-time, all that matters are: Properties, Events, and attributes on them.  This information is provided by the [TypeDescriptor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the Remarks section).  This information is freely changeable and affects only what in seen at design-time and is also used in data-binding.