# Add DesignerVerbs on a custom Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to add `DesignerVerbs` on a **custom form**? I have try to make a **custom designer class** for my **custom form class** and use it like this...

```
<Designer(GetType(CustomDesigner))>
Public Class CustomForm
    Inherits Form
    '...
End Class
```

I have also try to do all the "work" into my **custom form's class** like this...

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design

Public Class CustomForm
    Inherits Form
    '...
    Private _Verbs As DesignerVerbCollection
    Public ReadOnly Property Verbs() As DesignerVerbCollection
        Get
            If _Verbs Is Nothing Then
                _Verbs = New DesignerVerbCollection From {
                New DesignerVerb("Verb1", New EventHandler(AddressOf EventHandler1)),
                New DesignerVerb("Verb2", New EventHandler(AddressOf EventHandler2))
                }
                _Verbs(0).Visible = False
                _Verbs(1).Visible = True
            End If
            Return _Verbs
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub EventHandler1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        '...
    End Sub
    Private Sub EventHandler2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        '...
    End Sub
End Class
```

But with no luck.

Comment: Why do you have `Verbs` in `CustomForm`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei: In this case, for massive restoration of some properties.

Comment: The verbs that you want to show in designer, should come from the designer class which you registered for your form. You need to post `CustomDesigner` code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: I have create a custom designer with the verbs which I want to show, I "call" this custom designer class from my custom form's class, but nothing!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add DesignerVerb on UserControl's Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612004/add-designerverb-on-usercontrols-properties)

Comment: This is also related to your other question [Hide form's DoubleBuffered property without make it nonfunctional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037383/hide-forms-doublebuffered-property-without-make-it-nonfunctional) that uses the same technique to avoid writing a custom designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to add some custom verbs to designer of a `Form`, you need to create a new custom `Designer` by deriving from `DocumentDesigner` and overriding a lot of properties and method to recreate `FormDesigner`.

As an easier solution, you can tweak designer of base form of your form. Let's say, you have `Form1` and you want to have `Do Something` verb for it. To do so, if `BaseForm` is the base form for your `Form1`, it's enough to add the following code to `BaseForm`:

```cs
//You may want to add null checking to the code.

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if (!DesignMode)
        return;
    var host = (IDesignerHost)this.Site.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
    var designer = host.GetDesigner(this);
    designer.Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Do Something", (obj, args) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something done!");
    }));
}
```

As a result, *Do Something* will be added to context menu for your `Form1`:

[image]

If you like to go the harder way, here you can find the source code for [`FormDocumentDesigner`](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/WinForms/System/WinForms/Design/FormDocumentDesigner@cs/2/FormDocumentDesigner@cs) which is derived from [`DocumentDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.documentdesigner(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much Reza, it worked 100%!!! By the way, is there any link or something in case I want to study the hard way?

Comment: You're welcome :) Here you can find the source code for [`FormDocumentDesigner`](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/WinForms/System/WinForms/Design/FormDocumentDesigner@cs/2/FormDocumentDesigner@cs) which is derived from [`DocumentDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.documentdesigner(v=vs.110).aspx).